# Lareavel - Update or edit records through API

Tags: laravel

I am building APIs to read / create / update / edit records in database.
For read, I am using a resource. so all the fields from database are mapped to different properties. So outside world would not know the exact database table column name.

For example:
In database table i have price_paid, but in api response I have PricePaid.
So this work find for the read.

But now if I want to update that column, I have to have a form, that post value for price_paid. If I use PricePaid, obviously it does not exist.

What is a best way to map the PricePaid send in $request->PricePaid to price_paid?
I know I can have a something like this:

```
$itemObj = new item();
if(isset($request->PricePaid)){
    $itemObj->price_paid = $request->PricePaid;
}
$itemObj->save(). or $itemObj->update();
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: "Best" is a subjective term, and there's potentially lots of solutions here. The one you suggested isn't very flexible and would require you to check _every_ possible field for your `Item` Model. A quick solution would be an array map, like `public $conversions = ['price_paid' => 'PricePaid']`, then `foreach ($this->conversions as $column => $key) { $item->{$column} = $request->input($key, $item->{$column}); }`, which would dynamically set `price_paid` to the value of `PricePaid`, or it's existing value if not present in `$request`. But there are definitely "better" solutions out there.

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked. much better than my ways. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

In MVC the responsibility of the controller is to prepare client data and pass next to other layers.
One of technics is to make [request](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests) form class, validate it and pass to service (use case) layer for the next step. For example, add product.

Controller's action

```php
public function store(ProductCreateRequest $request, ProductCreateService $service)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();

    try {
        $service->createFromRequest($validated);
    } catch (DomainException $e) {
        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
            'product' => $e->getMessage(),
        ]);
    }
    
}
```

Service

```php
final class ProductCreateService
{
   private function create(array $data): void
   {
         // you will need to specify either a fillable or guarded property on your eloquent model class
         Product::create($data);
   }


   /**
    * @param array{Price: int} $requestData
    */
   public function createFromRequest(array $requestData): void
   {
        $this->create([
            'price' => $requestData['Price'],
        ]);
   }
}
```

Comment: This looks like more structural solution, but does it help to have the conversion in one place? currently I have the read response defined in a resource collection and the update defined in controller.

Comment: @user3534653 no it doesn't. If you are using Eloquent and wanna hide field names you may try to do it via [accessors and mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators)